# How to open a 'README.md' file in Windows 7?

Tags: git

I want to open a readme file of 'md' extension. I have tried a software to open all types of files, 'freefileviewer'. but this software is not getting installed on my Windows PC. Please help.

Comment: According to https://www.freefileviewer.com/formats.html, freefileviewer does not support Markdown (.md) files.

Comment: yeas, thanks for this. Any other alternative to open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.md` is an extension commonly associated with [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) files. At its core it is just a text file. You can open it with any texteditor or IDE that you like (notepad.exe, Notepad++, Wordpad, `type` in cmd, …)

Comment: I have tried opening it with notepad & wordpad, still not opened.

Comment: Then the file must be empty. _If_ it uses the `.md` extension to hint at a markdown file, it is text based. If it is a file of different type, you should still see its content. If it looks like garbage, it is likely a binary file. On GNU+Linux systems, you could use the `file` command to try find out which type of file it is. [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/) can also perform file-type detection (both not bulletproof, file type detection is based on heuristics)

Comment: Notepad++ has some support for markdown. Eclipse IDE has can edit and preview md files, I think most modern IDE have support due to heavy use of markdown in github repos.

Answer (score 3):

Markdown (.md) files are common text files. So you should be able to open it like if it's a .txt.

When I have to create .md files, I usually use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) , who provides a preview of your markdown.
In the image below an example of the view:

[image]